# PHP OOP: Is it possible to pass parameters to a class __destruct?

Tags: php, oop, destructor

If needed, parameters can be passed to a class via it's constructor.

```
class Test {

  public function __construct($echo) {
    echo $echo;
  }

}

$test = new Test('hello'); // Echos "hello"
```

Is there any way of passing parameters to the `__destruct`?

```
class Test {

  public function __construct($echo) {
    echo $echo;
  }

  public function __destruct($string) { // Is this possible?
    // Do something with this string
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, Destructors have only one signature

```
void __destruct ( void )
```

**[Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)**

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't seem to find that anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible.
But you can use a instance field like this:

```
class Test {
  var $value;
  public function __construct($echo) {
    this->value = $echo;
  }
  public function __destruct() {
    echo $this->value;
  }
}
```